# Powershell - Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The number of characters (0) in the argument is too small

Tags: powershell

Its my first day with powershell scripting
I am trying using VMM Cmdlet Get-SCVirtualMachine
it works fine when I use it like

```
PS C:\> $VM = Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name "VM01"
```

But it gives me an error when I try

```
PS C:\> $vmName = 'VM01'
PS C:\> $VM = Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name "$vmName"
```

The error I get is

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The number of characters
>   (0) in the argument is too small. Specify an argument whose length is
>   greater than or equal to "1" and then try the command again.

Can someone tell me what is it that I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What does `$vmName.GetType()` print? And `$vmName | Get-Member`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error using the code provided.  That error message is a result of a `[ValidateLength(1, x)]` attribute on the `Name` parameter, when the parameter value is `$null` or empty (has length 0).   The variable `$vmName` is somehow being reset prior to calling the cmdlet, which isn't possible with the code you posted.  This question cannot be answered without posting the actual original code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: As other have commented, the code as posted works. One likely cause of the issue is for there to be an additional line that defines `$vmname` as a different type. e.g `[bool]$vmname = $false` This can be resolved by using `Remove-Variable vmname`  prior to defining it the second time.

Comment: Pretty sure @BenH has got the right idea here

Comment: You don't need the quotes on `$vmName` with the function call... it should already be a string

Answer (score 0):

try

```
PS C:\> $vmName = "VM01"
PS C:\> $VM = Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name $vmName
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error

>Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null, >empty, or an element of the argument collection con
>tains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any >null values and then try the command again.

Answer (score 0):

The command looks OK and should work. Are you getting the error as a part of script or just by the example you posted?

You mention that you're using the `Get-SCPerformanceData` cmdlet and your example uses another cmdlet.

Try removing the quotes from the parameter, does it help?

Comment: I get the following error when I try without quotes : 
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection con
tains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.

Comment: Odd, can you test with a fresh console?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$vmName = '-Name VM01'
Get-SCVirtualMachine $vmName
```